# linear optimization problem with non-linear constraint

Tags: portfolio-optimization, optimization

I have the following optimisation problem which I want to solve using linear optimisation.

[image]

Is there a way to represent the second constraint in a linear form in order to be able to use linear optimisation ?

Comment: $\sum_i q_i p_i dur_i(metric_i-c)\leq 0$?

Comment: @Kermittfrog, that's what I was looking for. thanks!